# Sniff error in Scapy

Tags: python-2.7, scapy

I am trying to use scapy for one of my project. But, it gives the following error, When I test it.

> NameError: name 'sniff' is not defined

```
import sys
from scapy import *


devices = set()

def PacketHandler(pkt):

    if pkt.haslayer(Dot11) :

        dot11_layer = pkt.getlayer(Dot11)

        if dot11_layer.addr2 and ( dot11_layer.addr2 not in devices ):
            devices.add(dot11_layer.addr2)
            print dot11_layer.addr2

sniff(iface = sys.argv[1], count = int(sys.argv[2]), prn = PacketHandler)
```

if I change module name to scapy.all, it says there is no module.

Python version: 2.7
Scapy version: 2.3.3

I have just installed with pip install scapy.Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the error?

Comment: Hi @Noob123. Please see the output error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_wifi.py", line 18, in <module>
    sniff(iface = sys.argv[1], count = int(sys.argv[2]), prn = PacketHandler)
NameError: name 'sniff' is not defined

Answer (score 3):

You must import Scapy as `from scapy.all import *`, and **you must not name your script `scapy.py`** (or any other script in the current directory or your `PYTHONPATH`)!

Comment: Hi @Pierre. When use from scapy.all import *. it says there is no module named scapy.all. When I change to from scapy import *, it gives the sniff error. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Pierre. Thanks once again for your help. Yes, I've already checked it. Unfortunately, it did not work. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mysaypay.py", line 2, in <module>
    from scapy.all import *
ImportError: No module named scapy.all

Comment: You probably either have an old (v1.x) version of scapy installed somewhere, or another script or directory named scapy. Can you run `python2 -c "import scapy; print scapy.__file__"`?

Comment: No really. I tried on my mac as well. I have got the same issue. The version of scapy is : 2.3.3. I installed via pip install scapy on both windows and mac. When I tried to import directly on terminal, its working fine. On the otherside, it does not work.

Comment: Can you add to your script, after the `imports`: `import scapy; print scapy.__file__` and let me know the result?

Comment: Hi @Pierre. Thanks again for your help. The output is : C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\__init__.pyc

Comment: You mean: `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\__init__.pyc` (with the `\` before `__init__` and two `_` before and after `init`)? Is there a file `all.py` and/or `all.pyc` in `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\`?

Comment: Yes, there is all.py and all.pyc in the site-packages/scapy folder.